# Override used classes in parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, namespaces

Suppose there is a class `NiceClass` using some other class `LesserClass` in a place I can't edit

```
# NiceClass.py

class LesserClass:
    ...
    # stuff
    ...

class NiceClass:
    ...
    # Lots of use of lesser class in here...
    ...
```

Now I want to use my own class `MyLesserClass` instead of `LesserClass` everywhere in an inherited version of `NiceClass`

```
# MyNiceClass.py

from NiceClass import NiceClass
from NiceClass import LesserClass as oldLesserClass

class LesserClass(oldLesserClass):
    ...
    # Some extra stuff
    ...

class MyNiceClass(NiceClass):
    ...
    # Everywhere LesserClass was used I now want to use MyLesserClass
    ...
```

But all the non-overridden methods in `MyNiceClass` will use the `LesserClass` from the old `NiceClass.py`.

Everything would work as I want if I just copy-pasted in the whole definition of `NiceClass` into `MyNiceClass.py`.

It's like I just want to inherit the source code and not the whole namespace. Maybe inheritence is the wrong way?

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Please try to provide more clarity. What is your expectation and issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is only limited to methods under `NiceClass` using the class `LesserClass`.

Now if you want the methods inside `MyNiceClass` to use `MyLesserClass` instead of `LesserClass` then you could update the `__globals__` dict of those methods and make the name `'LesserClass'` point to `MyLesserClass`.

Here's a simple example demonstrating the same by overriding [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__):

```
class A:
    a = 'A.a'
    b = 'A.b'


class B:
    def func_a(self):
        print(A.a)

    def func_b(self):
        print(A.b)


class C:
    a = 'C.a'
    b = 'C.b'


class D(B):
    def func_a(self):
        print(C.a)

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        value = object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
        if callable(value):
            value = update_namespace(value, {'old': {'name': 'A', 'obj': A}, 'new': {'obj': C}})
        return value


def update_namespace(func, namespace):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Update the globals
        func.__globals__[namespace['old']['name']] = namespace['new']['obj']
        val = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # Restore it back to the actual value
        func.__globals__[namespace['old']['name']] = namespace['old']['obj']
        return val
    return wrapper


d = D()
d.func_a()  # This should print C.a
d.func_b()  # This should print C.b
```

**Output:**

```
C.a
C.b
```